# Highlight current week when datepicker is loaded

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am following [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manishma/AVZJh/) to be able to highlight and select whole week from datepicker.

I have customized it to work with jQuery 1.9 by changing [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) to [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on). Here is the edited [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZedBee/2zGXv/). It works fine but in its current state the week is only highlighted once the user click on a date.

What I want to achieve is to highlight (and populate dates in startDate and endDate vars) the week to which current date belongs automatically on startup without clicking current date. I have tried the following but it doesn't seem to work

```
var currentDate = $(".week-picker").datepicker("getDate");
var onSelectFunction = $(".week-picker").datepicker("option","onSelect");

var format  = $(".week-picker").datepicker( "option", "dateFormat" );

var currDate = $.datepicker.formatDate(format,currentDate)
onSelectFunction( currDate );
```

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$(function () {
    var startDate;
    var endDate;

    var selectCurrentWeek = function () {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            $('.week-picker').find('.ui-datepicker-current-day a').addClass('ui-state-active')
        }, 1);
    }
    var $weekPicker = $('.week-picker');

    function updateWeekStartEnd() {
        var date = $weekPicker.datepicker('getDate') || new Date();
        startDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay());
        endDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 6);
    }

    updateWeekStartEnd();

    function updateDateText(inst) {
        var dateFormat = inst != 'start' &&  inst.settings.dateFormat ? inst.settings.dateFormat : $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat;

        console.log( dateFormat)
        $('#startDate').text($.datepicker.formatDate(dateFormat, startDate, inst.settings));
        $('#endDate').text($.datepicker.formatDate(dateFormat, endDate, inst.settings));
    }

    updateDateText('start');

    $weekPicker.datepicker({
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
            updateWeekStartEnd();
            updateDateText(inst);
            selectCurrentWeek();
        },
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            var cssClass = '';
            if (date >= startDate && date <= endDate) cssClass = 'ui-datepicker-current-day';
            return [true, cssClass];
        },
        onChangeMonthYear: function (year, month, inst) {
            selectCurrentWeek();
        }
    });

    selectCurrentWeek();

    $('.week-picker .ui-datepicker-calendar tr').on('mousemove', function () {
        $(this).find('td a').addClass('ui-state-hover');
    });
    $('.week-picker .ui-datepicker-calendar tr').on('mouseleave', function () {
        $(this).find('td a').removeClass('ui-state-hover');
    });

});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/eFzG4/

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. But I also need to select a date some times. User will select either a date range or a specific date. How can I make it work in this?

Comment: @Murali should be fairly easy to add a set of radios, or a checkbox so user can select whole week or just a day. Then not run any of the "week" code above if it is in day mode

Comment: Try this with `firstDay: 1` and it won't work properly.

Comment: @lejon you would need to adjust `updateWeekStartEnd()`

Answer (score 1):

you can also trigger click on the current day

```
$(".ui-datepicker-current-day").click();
```