# JQUI Week picker won't start on this week

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a week-picker [[FIDDLE]](http://jsfiddle.net/2q3u1g2z/1/), I can't get it to have the current week selected on load. So far I only have the current day selected.

Also, is there an easier way to do a week-picker than this?

Here's the Code:

```
    var startDate;
    var endDate;

    var selectCurrentWeek = function (where) {
        console.log(where);
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            $('.week-picker').find('.ui-datepicker-current-day a').addClass('ui-state-active');

        }, 1);
    }

    $('.week-picker').datepicker({
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
            var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            startDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay());
            endDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 6);
            var dateFormat = inst.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat;
            $('#startDate').text($.datepicker.formatDate(dateFormat, startDate, inst.settings));
            $('#endDate').text($.datepicker.formatDate(dateFormat, endDate, inst.settings));

            selectCurrentWeek("week-picker");
        },
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            var cssClass = '';
            if (date >= startDate && date <= endDate)
                cssClass = 'ui-datepicker-current-day';
            return [true, cssClass];
        },
        onChangeMonthYear: function (year, month, inst) {
            selectCurrentWeek("change");
        }
    });

    $(document).on('mousemove', '.week-picker .ui-datepicker-calendar tr', function () { $(this).find('td a').addClass('ui-state-hover'); });
    $(document).on('mouseleave', '.week-picker .ui-datepicker-calendar tr', function () { $(this).find('td a').removeClass('ui-state-hover'); });
```

Comment: In `beforeShowDay`, `startDate` and `endDate` are undefined.

Comment: OK, I used the definitions for start and end date in onSelect, and put them in beforeShowDay, but that didn't work. Not sure why tho. http://jsfiddle.net/ye0zz6da/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Highlight current week when datepicker is loaded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14673277/highlight-current-week-when-datepicker-is-loaded) or http://stackoverflow.com/q/26686307/2333214.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a ghetto way to do it, but it works. Basically, you want to trigger a click event on the current day. So I added to my $(document).ready function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".ui-datepicker-today").trigger("click");
});
```

If anyone has a better solution, that would be great.